# Where does GNOME Disks store the Benchmark history?

Tags: disk-management, gnome-disk-utility, benchmarks

So I've been using Disks (or gnome-disks) to benchmark some drives I have plugged in including internal ones. When it does so it keeps a history of past marks so it's good to look back and check. This can be brought up by selecting the drive and opening the Benchmark option.

But what about external disks? The history of external disks would be kept as well. But I cannot access it from the user interface. I don't want to locate and physically plug in a drive just to look up information. Since it obviously has stored it itself.

I can track down screen shots of past marks I took. But that's not very efficient when wanting to simply look at past results of benchmarks. So where does Disks store results? Can they actually be looked up from the interface? I didn't see any way about it so it would be a good future feature to be able to look up past results without needing the drive plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

They're stored in `by-id-<interface>-<device model>-<device serial number>.gnome-disks-benchmark` files under `~/.cache/gnome-disks/benchmarks`. Problem is it seems to keep only the last benchmark per device, and to my knowledge it provides no straightforward way to access the data from unplugged devices.

As a workaround, you can just change the name of the desired file to correspond to one of the drives currently plugged in to your PC, and then open the benchmark dialog for that device in Disks. So screenshots might be less of a hassle, unfortunately.

Been looking into this because I'm trying to use the raw data elsewhere, but I haven't found a way to parse the files so far. I'll update this if I find a better solution to your problem.